# Asp Net MVC Role Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I am stuck with roles in my asp net mvc 5 project.I can create role type on database but cannot retrive them into User registration, as it display an error on my Register.cshtml **"There is no ViewData item of type '' that has the key 'Name"**. Can anyone please help me.
thanks in advance.
Here is my controller:

```
 private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
            private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
            ApplicationDbContext context;
            public AccountController()
            {       

            }

            public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
            {
                UserManager = userManager;
                SignInManager = signInManager;
                context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
```

My Register Action

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

            return View(model);
        }
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Select Your User Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Name")

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

although i have posted another way to find the roles but your code us fine did you enter any roles in table

> AspNetRoles

and created the relation between user and roles in table

> AspNetUserRoles

To find all the role for specific user you can use the following code

```
    RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ApplicationUser au = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == "admin@admin.com");

    foreach (IdentityUserRole role in au.Roles)
    {
        string name = role.RoleId;
        string RoleName = context.Roles.First(r => r.Id == role.RoleId).Name;
    }
```

Code for Creating Roles Write these lines in **protected override void Seed(RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)** in **cofiguration.cs**

```
    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "User"))
    {
        var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
        var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "User" };

        manager.Create(role);
    }
```

Code for attaching users to role Write these lines in **protected override void Seed(RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)** in **cofiguration.cs**

```
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin@admin.com"))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@admin.com", Email = "admin@admin.com" };
        manager.Create(user, "password");
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
    }
```

To bring the roles for specific user you have to write this code.

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
string userId = user != null ? user.Id : null;
var roles = userId != null ? UserManager.GetRoles(userId) : null;
if (roles != null)
{
    foreach (var item in roles)
    {
        //Assign user roles
        UserManager.AddToRole(userId, item);
    }
}
```

and to get All the Roles do this

```
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var roles = context.Roles;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  yes I have managed to insert roles on ASpNetRoles but I cannot bring them to my AspNetUsers, as it brings am error as stated on the top of this post.